# Keep the memory to last value of the variable

Tags: lua, esp8266, pwm

I am using ESP8266 and i am programming it with Lua language. I created a PWM function and i created a server in ESP8266. I can change PWM duty cycle through this server(You can see figure). First i set to PWM with a default value and i am changing the PWM through server with respect to my application. But when i disconnected the ESP8266 from power and connected again to power, duty cycle returned to default value. I want to save last PWM value that i entered through server and when i disconnected the ESP8266 from power and connected again to power, duty cycle set the PWM value to last value i entered through server. For example on the below i set the default PWM value to '512', when i changed the PWM with respect to my application, i saved the last value and after the reconnecting process(i informed above) i took the last PWM value from memory and PWM duty cycle starts with this value. Is there any permanent memory like EEPROM i can use to save last PWM value or any other solution anyone suggest? (i have to use Lua language)

[PWM adjusting server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZJKI.jpg)

```
--default PWM value 
pwm.setup(2,1000,512);
pwm.start(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to persist data so that it survives power cycling then you have to write it to flash memory through the SPIFFS file system. File write example from the [docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/file/#filewrite):

```
-- open 'init.lua' in 'a+' mode
file.open("init.lua", "a+")
-- write 'foo bar' to the end of the file
file.write('foo bar')
file.close()
```

If you need something less permanent then you can use the [`rtcmem` module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/rtcmem/) which provides access to RTC memory. The data held there will at least survive deep sleeps.

Comment: Thank you so much,i have handled using SPIFFS file system.

Comment: Then please [accept and/or upvote this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/257994) so that Stack Overflow can mark it as such.